# Nuget failing to normalize for one of third party package

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, cicd, semantic-versioning

I don't have dev-ops experience as of yet.

I am trying to fix the CI part of CI/CD process on Azure.

Also we are using the Nuget latest version

currently the build for the project is failing because of one library that is `Serilog.Enrichers.Span.3.0.0`

CI script giving us the following; it downloads the package successfully.

```
2023-07-25T17:14:13.7200079Z Restoring NuGet package Serilog.Enrichers.Span.3.0.0.
2023-07-25T17:14:13.7244723Z   GET https://www.myget.org/F/caary/auth/***********************/api/v2/Packages(Id='Serilog.Enrichers.Span',Version='3.0.0')
2023-07-25T17:14:13.7275362Z   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog.enrichers.span/3.0.0/serilog.enrichers.span.3.0.0.nupkg
2023-07-25T17:14:13.7353161Z   OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/serilog.enrichers.span/3.0.0/serilog.enrichers.span.3.0.0.nupkg 18ms
2023-07-25T17:14:13.7353844Z Acquiring lock for the installation of Serilog.Enrichers.Span 3.0.0
```

but that is how it adds package folder on the path:

```
2023-07-25T17:14:15.3666357Z Adding package 'Serilog.Enrichers.Span.3.0.0+build.482' to folder 'f:\z\1\s\packages'
2023-07-25T17:14:15.3759924Z Added package 'Serilog.Enrichers.Span.3.0.0+build.482' to folder 'f:\z\1\s\packages'
```

Note : it created the directory name of the package with Semantic version: **Serilog.Enrichers.Span.3.0.0+build.482**

Now, when the `dotnet` starts to compile, it tries to look for the above package in following path and ends up giving an error; also build fails:

```
2023-07-25T17:15:00.2353455Z           Considered "F:\z\1\s\packages\Serilog.Enrichers.Span.3.0.0\lib\net472\Serilog.Enrichers.Span.dll", but it didn't exist.
```

Note : Above path is the normalized version check (exact as it exists in `csproj` file)

```
<HintPath>..\packages\Serilog.Enrichers.Span.3.0.0\lib\net472\Serilog.Enrichers.Span.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Besides this package, every other package downloads and compiles up perfectly.

Why nuget is failing to normalize this package ?
What are the optimal solution to handle package with above semantic version?

P.S. This issue has taken alot of my time, Help will be appreciated, thanks.